# EasyOCR Printing file details instead of text output only

Tags: python, easyocr

I am trying to test out Easy OCR. Now when I run my code

```
path = "{image file}"
read = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=True)
result = read.readtext(path)
print(result)
```

It outputs this

```
[([[887, 1], [975, 1], [975, 13], [887, 13]], 'Photoshop PSD hle', 0.7655935865739645), 
([[978, 2], [1022, 2], [1022, 10], [978, 10]], 'Jownioao', 0.2720053768871571), 
([[1044, 2], [1152, 2], [1152, 10], [1044, 10]], 'Resolution 1230x1024P}', 0.3419384126594147), 
([[1169, 2], [1274, 2], [1274, 10], [1169, 10]], 'uDsooradhics cor', 0.10438481226211914), 
([[285, 474], [980, 474], [980, 716], [285, 716]], 'TEXT', 0.999515175819397)]
```

Instead of just

```
([[285, 474], [980, 474], [980, 716], [285, 716]], 'TEXT', 0.999515175819397)]
```

I want to get an simple output but it seems it also prints the image details and such.

EDIT: Sorry I posted a wrong output. If anyone is wondering here's the link of the [photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VB8qAFm0f3A4ncvdiCkSQjy9auVxM__o/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is explained in the [repo](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR): "The output will be in a list format, each item represents a bounding box, the text detected and confident level, respectively."

You can set `detail=0` for simpler output:

```
result = read.readtext(path, detail = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you it filtered out exactly the text though it gave me this output
['Photoshop PSD hle', 'Jownioao', 'Resolution 1230x1024P}', 'uDsooradhics cor', 'TEXT'] instead of just "TEXT"

Comment: try this then: `result = read.readtext(path, detail = 0)[-1]`

Comment: It works! but it also affects other input. What does [-1] at the end do?

Comment: It just takes the last item from the list.